# Netplan configuration for bridge and route setup

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, netplan

I'm not very versed in netplan. Basic static IPs and VLANs are all I've really done.

I need to get this set of commands to persist on reboot:

```
ip link add loop-to-lan link eno1 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.10.7/32 dev loop-to-lan
ip link set loop-to-lan up
ip route add 192.168.10.6 dev loop-to-lan
```

in order to accommodate ipvlan and macvlan networks from Docker containers. There is an odd lack of examples on how to do this, but I found one and adapted it for the above commands, but I clearly botched it because when I do `netplan try --timeout 10`, I lose connectivity to the host (where netplan is running) until netplan reverts.

```
  bridges:
    loop-to-lan:
      interfaces: [eno1]
      addresses: [192.68.10.7/32]
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.10.6
          via: 192.168.10.7
```

Note that the host is 192.168.10.2/24. I just needed to kick a container off the host IP so I could reuse ports.

Any ideas what is wrong with that netplan config?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question can be found here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1664847/comments/19

...only he called his interface `macvlan0` where yours is `loop-to-lan`.

Comment: please add the specifics of the change from the link, as link only answers get stall over time.